# Creating Slot Machine Android

Tags: android, slot

Good Day.Im trying to make a slot machine game.Im running into huge problems of making slot machine like logic.First i tried to use the listView and infinite scroll but no success as its horribly not good to use one billion items into listView just to spin some items.Second i used ScrollView with ObjectAnimator but it pauses for second onAnimationRepeat method so no luck there too.Third i uses Google WhellDemo code buts its not slot more likely just a date picker and animation of that picker not as i wanted.So i started to make my own.I got the layout,got the linearLayout inside it and got 3 imagViews inside LinearLayout.Im starting animation on Linear Layout with this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:repeatCount="4"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

However i got one more item OUTSIDE of visible area for user.That one item should pop down when animation start.So by logic whenever animation starts.the 3 visible items must go down and the 4th invisible item must be going down and become visible too.The problem is that animation starst,the 3 items goes down,but the forth item not visible and not going down with  them too...!Here is my layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slots_view_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/slots_view_2"
        android:background="#ffffff">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstSlotInnerLayout_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/firstVisibleItem"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_12" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/firstVisibleItem"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_01" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sa"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_01" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/safasdfa"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_11"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/safasfa"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_12"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/safgasga"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_09"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gsagas"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_08"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gfasgas"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/symbol_02"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

Above I'm attaching the image of how it looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vwmw.png)

The blue circle is the invisible item by logic which must go down whenever i start animation on my linearLayout but what i want doesn't Happening.Please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A slot machine should not be programmed with a ListView. Have a look at [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) :)

Comment: Are you looking for an infinite-scroll ListView?

Comment: yes!thats definatally what i was looking for!

Comment: you can refer this https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ this may help you

Comment: check this out : [SlotMachine](https://github.com/smanikandan14/SlotMachine)

Answer (score 1):

Actually none of above comments helped me,neither google did.So i tried to do it on my own and i have made it!Pretty fast what should be done to get slot like logic.You need 5 or 3 scrollViews,as you want,need to fill scrollViews with images and just about  70 images will do its trick(will make you fell like the wheel is spinning),and you need to have AnimatorSets!Ok so first what you do is you call FullScrollDown on the scrollView,or fullScrollUp(based on your requirements) afterwards on SPIN button click you apply object animator with animator sets with 'SCROLL' parameters and your good to go with your wheel.Thats how i achieve it.

Comment: share any GITHUB link